# "Please unlock disk mmcblk0p3_crypt " error on surface tablet

Tags: boot, grub2

I tried to install Ubuntu on my Surface 3 tablet, and it went thru the install pretty good, but when it booted up from the install, it had this message "please unlock disk mmcblk0p3_crypt". I can't type anything, or select anything. I've tried powering off and booting up again, but no luck. What does this message mean, and how can I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried the [Kernel packages for Microsoft Surface devices](https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/kernel)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No I haven't tried that, thanks for pointing me in that direction. I'm totally new to Linux, that's why I want to try it, and learn :). I will try it and comment if it works.

Comment: How do I know which one to download? Also, is it normal to have a bunch of errors generated after you select which OS to boot into? I select "ubuntu" and then some errors are generated, and then it shows what I wrote in my original question-please unlock disk...

Comment: Did you install the Ubuntu selecting the encrypt filesystem option ? -- If you did it, You can reinstall the ubuntu without that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a Surface 3, but there are many pages showing some [instructions](https://www.returngis.net/2016/09/instalar-ubuntu-en-tu-surface-pro-3/) may help you.

> how can I proceed?

1. If you have installed ubuntu with disk encryption, re-install the ubuntu disabling the disk encryption.
2. When your ubuntu boots the first time, install the [linux kernel packages for Surface](https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/kernel).

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tigerite/kernel
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install linux-surface
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. I'm posting this from it right now. The main problem was the disk encryption, I still am working at installing the kernel package